# Laravel where query not geting all value (can't get null value)

Tags: laravel, null, where-clause

I have a table called `tb_user` with multiple fields, 1 of them is `id_company`.
When showing the user list, admin can set whether they want to see all users or specific users with selected `id_company`.

In the query, I set it dynamically so that when admin set it to all or not the query still can work. This is my query :

```php
if ($id_company == 'all') {
    $idSign = '!=';
} else {
    $idSign = '=';
}
->where('tb_user.id_company', $idSign, $id_company);
```

Now the problem is when admin select all user, query isn't returning all result.
When id_company is null, this query isn't returning the value.
What should I do so that this query, when set all, can return value where id_company is both null and not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user choose all, so you just don't need to put the where at all.

To do this, break your query in many steps:

```
$query = YourModel::query();

if ($id_company !== 'all') {
    $query->where('tb_user.id_company', $id_company);
}

$result = $query->get(); // or paginate if you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your naming is very unconventional. If `id_company` is a foreign key to a company table, it should be named `company_id`.
ID's are mostly integers, so a value of `all` is not very straightforward. Instead of setting the filter value to `all`, I would recommend to not set it at all. 
That way you simply have

```php
$users = TBUser::query();
if (!empty($id_company)) {
    $users->where('id_company', $id_company);
}
return $users->get();
```